# Admin search post meta

Tags: customization, admin, filters, search

I have currently built a property database using WordPress and am purely using the back-end for the whole job. I am listing all the properties and used a plugin called "Easy Filter" to add custom taxonomy filters, however, I also have custom meta that's added on the post and displayed on the `edit.php` page. I used a function to do a direct search and have the ability to pull all the custom meta. (see below code)

I was wondering if anyone knew how I can change the value to be like an "includes" instead of a ==. Basically, if there is a building name called "Kam Fai Mansion" and I search the building name meta with the term "Kam" it would also show the results as right now it says nothing found because it is looking for an exact match for the building name instead of containing the word "Kam" within it.

```
//START SEARCH ADMIN
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'ba_admin_posts_filter' );
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );
function ba_admin_posts_filter( $query )
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'];
    if (isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']) && $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'] != '')
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'];
    }
}
function ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_key FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' ORDER BY 1';
    $fields = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N);
?>
<select name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME">
<option value=""><?php _e('Filter By Custom Fields', 'baapf'); ?></option>
<?php
    $current = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_NAME']:'';
    $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (substr($field[0],0,1) != "_"){
        printf
            (
                '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                $field[0],
                $field[0] == $current? ' selected="selected"':'',
                $field[0]
            );
        }
    }
?>
</select> <?php _e('Value:', 'baapf'); ?><input type="TEXT" name="ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE" value="<?php echo $current_v; ?>" />
<?php
}
//END SEARCH ADMIN
```